# JavaFX - how to get instance of the controller object

Tags: java, javafx

How do I get a reference to my controller class?

Here is my code snippet.

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("my.fxml"));
stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
MyController c = stage.getControllerInstance(); <-- HOW???
c.setATextValue("Hello world"); //Set initial value
stage.show();
```

The Controller class is specified in FXML in the **fx:controller** attribute. The instance gets created automatically in the background. I need access to that instance in order to set initial values in the form.

I know I can set the initial values in XML, but I need to set them at runtime.

Comment: I think you should use FXMLLoader's method getController()

Answer (score 23):

Don't use the static `FXMLLoader.load(...)` method. Instead, create an `FXMLLoader` instance and call `load()` on the instance. Then you can call `getController()`:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("my.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
MyController c = loader.getController();

stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
```