# JavaFX controller is null when instantiated

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, scenebuilder

I have been stuck on this for hours. I don't know why my controller from JavaFX is pointing to null. I made a JavaFX GUI in `scene builder`, added the controller class to my project with its appropriate skeleton code. But when I instantiate the controller in my `start` method it is pointing to null.

#### App.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static SampleController controller;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("testProjectFx.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            controller = (SampleController) loader.getController();
            System.out.println("controller is : " + controller);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

            stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

#### SampleController.java

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class SampleController {

    @FXML
    private Label firstLabel;

}
```

#### testProjectFx.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="firstLabel" layoutX="314.0" layoutY="135.0" text="Label" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

#### Error stacktrace

```
cd /home/hexaquarks/vscode/testProject ; /usr/bin/env /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java --module-path /home/hexaquarks/Downloads/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.swing -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @/tmp/cp_s5yrrw0jqsav930qkowo7m19.argfile App 
Aug. 11, 2021 1:30:27 P.M. javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 16 by JavaFX runtime of version 11.0.2
controller is : null
```

with folder tree:

```
Testproject
├── .vscode
├── bin
├── lib
└── src
    ├── App.java
    ├── SampleController.java
    └── testProjectFx.fxml
```

---

I followed the instructions mentionned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751271/accessing-fxml-controller-class) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457811/javafx-how-to-get-instance-of-the-controller-object), and some other StackOverflow pages. I am reproducing the instructions exactly as they are mentioned but I still get my controller as null.

I am short of ideas, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to manually add `fx:controller="SampleController"` in the root tag of the `.fxml` document which in my case was the `<AnchorPane>` tag, now it works.

```
<AnchorPane (...) fx:controller="SampleController">
   <children>
      (...)
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

If one is using "Scene Builder" then go in the bottom left "controller" tab and input in the text field "controller class" the chosen instance name that is given in the `start()` method.